# R 'newdata' had 7 rows but variables found have 182 rows

Tags: r

I am trying the following:

```
model_lr <- lm(metrics$Rev_Per_Player~metrics$Promo + metrics$DoW)

DoW <- wday(c(2,3,4,5,6,7,1), label = TRUE)
Promo <- c("","A","","B", "A","B", "")
Players <- c(3000,4000,4000,5000,6000,6000,7000)

new_ds <- data.frame(Promo,DoW,Players)

predict(model_lr,newdata = new_ds[,1:2])
```

I end up getting this warning:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 7 rows but variables found have 182 rows
```

All the explanations I found for this problem have to do with inapropriately  naming the new datasets' input features, which is something that I am accounting for already.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you try: `lm(Rev_Per_Player ~ Promo + DoW, data = metrics)`

Example:

```
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
mod2 <- lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$hp)
newdata <- data.frame(mpg = 5, hp = 200)

## Works
predict(mod1, newdata)

## Doesn't Work
predict(mod2, newdata)
```

Why?

I believe it has to do with the fact that the model.frames are different depending on how you specify the variables used in the analysis. `lm()` uses the model.frame to actually run the regression algorithm.

Try the following. The naming conventions are different.

```
model.frame(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
model.frame(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$hp)
```

Comment: I had tried it already but unfortunately it didn't work. I just decided to clean all the environment and run it again, which did the trick for me.