# 3D scatterplot done with plot3D producing strange behaviour

Tags: r, scatter3d, plot3d

I'm trying to display a plane of best fit within a 3D scatter plot using the library `plot3D`. When the code below is run everything seems fine enough, but if I replace the `fit` with the second `fit` I get strange behaviour, the plane is no longer a flat plane. I expect both versions to produce the same picture. What's going on?

[image]

```
library(plot3D)

df <- structure(list(X = 1:10, TV = c(230.1, 44.5, 17.2, 151.5, 180.8, 
8.7, 57.5, 120.2, 8.6, 199.8), radio = c(37.8, 39.3, 45.9, 41.3, 
10.8, 48.9, 32.8, 19.6, 2.1, 2.6), newspaper = c(69.2, 45.1, 
69.3, 58.5, 58.4, 75, 23.5, 11.6, 1, 21.2), sales = c(22.1, 10.4, 
9.3, 18.5, 12.9, 7.2, 11.8, 13.2, 4.8, 10.6)), .Names = c("X", 
"TV", "radio", "newspaper", "sales"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


x<-df$TV
y<-df$radio
z<-df$sales

fit <- lm(z ~ x + y)
# fit <- lm(df$sales ~ df$TV + df$radio)

x.pred <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 5)
y.pred <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = 5)
xy <- expand.grid( x = x.pred, y = y.pred)

z.pred <- matrix(predict(fit, newdata = xy), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

scatter3D(x, y, z,
    surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **Both fits are correct. However the second `predict` is not finding the right column names to predict.**

---

If you want the second fit to work use:

```r
fit <- lm(sales ~ TV + radio, data=df)
...
xy <- expand.grid(TV = x.pred, radio = y.pred)
```

Why? Because `predict` always searches for the column name it was trained in `newdata`.

You may note that the first line in the code above also changed, we are no longer using the `df$var` format, instead we use the `data` argument. This happens because when using this format `fit$model` is equals to:

```
   df$sales df$TV df$radio
1      22.1 230.1     37.8
2      10.4  44.5     39.3
3       9.3  17.2     45.9
...
```

And we can't name column names with "$" dollar sign. In other words we can't do:

```r
fit <- lm(df$sales ~ df$TV + df$radio)
...
xy <- expand.grid(df$TV = x.pred, df$radio = y.pred)
```

Because it will throw an error.

---

As stated above, both fits are, indeed, correct. If you run,

```r
fit <- lm(z ~ x + y)
fit
```

you will get,

> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)            x            y
> 2.08052      0.05598      0.15282

and with,

```r
fit <- lm(df$sales ~ df$TV + df$radio)
fit
```

you will get,

> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)            x            y
> 2.08052      0.05598      0.15282

as well.

---

Finally, note that when `predict` with `newdata` can't find the right variables names, you will get a warning message like this:

```
'newdata' had 25 rows but variables found have 10 rows
```

Which in my opinion should be an error. But it may get fixed in next versions. Some other sources about this issue are:

- [Getting Warning: " 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 32 rows" on predict.lm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464893/getting-warning-newdata-had-1-row-but-variables-found-have-32-rows-on-pred)
- [R 'newdata' had 7 rows but variables found have 182 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047204/r-newdata-had-7-rows-but-variables-found-have-182-rows)
- [Warning message 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 16 rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195192/warning-message-newdata-had-1-row-but-variables-found-have-16-rows-in-r)
- [R Warning: newdata' had 15 rows but variables found have 22 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978688/r-warning-newdata-had-15-rows-but-variables-found-have-22-rows)